# Tradingview Alert to Webhook URL

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

I have a pine script strategy in Tradingview platform and I would like to ask, is it possible to send alert message directly from strategy script to webhook URL, not via Alerts (when etry / exit conditions of the strategy are met)

code is like this:

```
bullish = tk_cross_bull and cs_cross_bull and price_above_kumo
bearish = tk_cross_bear and cs_cross_bear and price_below_kumo


strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=bullish and long_entry)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=bearish and short_entry)

strategy.close("Long", when=bearish and not short_entry)
strategy.close("Short", when=bullish and not long_entry)
```

So, when bullish / bearish condition is met -> entry / exit happens,

How to then add and alert to send info to Webhook?

My thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use alerts?

Comment: HTTP webhooks have many parameters which would look ugly if you had to define them in your scripts, so these webhooks, along with its parameters, are decoupled, and as their purpose are similar, they are decoupled into Alerts. Alerts - in case of the webhooks - are just a formalized way of defining the HTTP endpoint, the payload, etc. They are dynamic so you can decide from the script which content you want to send (it does not have to be fixed in the Alert). And you can have more than 1 alert on a script -> you can have multiple endpoints if you want that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. You must use alerts for this purpose.